# ByteArrayOutputStream encoding issue

Tags: java, android, character-encoding, http-post

I have issue on encoding, after i download data of rss feed from website. Some character does not interpret properly.
I use `HttpResponse.getEntity()` and put in loop read inputStream and write in `ByteArrayOutPutStream`.

E.g. ByteArrayOutPutStream bs;
after write on "bs", i use

`String test = bs.toString("UTF-8");`

however some character comes like this:

> Mytestï¼è¾å¸éï¼å°±è¢«æèªé²å¥é»å­éµä»¶ç³»çµ±ä¸äºéç¥å®¢æ¶

I cannot convert those character, any idea.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not in `UTF-8` encoding, it's likely in `Big5` encoding (your question history confirms that you're from China / Hong Kong).

> Mytest簿翹癡職疇繡矇簿翹疇簞簣癡瞽竄疆癡穠矇簡疇瞼矇罈疇簫矇繕瓣罈繞癟糧罈癟繕簣瓣繡瓣繙矇癟瞼疇簧瞽疆繞

You should be able to determine that by reading `HttpEntity#getContentType()` yourself. It should return something like

```
text/html;charset=Big5
```

Comment: @BalusC: can you please let me know, how did u find out, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Suresh: convert them back to bytes using UTF-8 and then read hex patterns.

Comment: It does not work, yeah right that is chinese character. However, when i retrieve string in xml form it show : ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> and getContentType().Name always return "Content-Type" and value return "text/xml" it does not return chartset; from HttpEntity.getContentType().

Comment: The `ï»¿` indicates that you're reading or printing it to console/file as CP1252 or ISO-8859 instead of UTF-8. Was that Chinese content part of the XML response? XML is supposed to be always in UTF-8. Probably the other end did it incorrectly. What is the URL?

Comment: As per your comment on the other answer, you're getting "an exception" when using Big5. If it was an `UnsupportedEncodingException`, then it means that your platform doesn't support this charset and that you have to install the charset on the platform first. Big5 works for me on default Win7 x64 setup with latest Java 1.6. Likely Android simply doesn't support the charset.

Comment: Error only throw if i use saxparser. However, Big5 interpret in chinese but it lost all english character. Url:http://www.epsilon.com/RSS/PressReleasesRSS.aspx?reg=11

Comment: That URL shows fine here using UTF-8 on my Eclipse UTF-8 console. You are apparently simply not outputting/displaying the result the right way. I however wonder how you end up with a malformed Big5 string. Was it from a different URL or something? As to hex patterns, just convert byte array to hex string. Recognizing and relating the patterns to a certain charset is however a whole story apart :)

Comment: Thank you, finally, i solved a problem. I use "ISO-8859-1", below details how i solved those issue : suppose i have string - String test = "èªç©ºæ¥­çåå¼·èå®¢æºéå¢ä¸å¯æ", then i did String t = new String(st.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")); and t gets in converted value. thank you

Comment: @user533710: this is *definitely* not the right solution. Your ugly hack is relying on the platform default encoding and the code will break when you run it on other platforms. You need to ensure that the stream comes in with UTF-8 bytes and that you parse it to chars using UTF-8 charset and that you manipulate it as UTF-8 and that you streams it as UTF-8 bytes to the display and that the display uses UTF-8 charset to interpret it.

Comment: BalusC - Sorry for delay reply, you are right, it is ugly hack. I change using UTF-8 it works. Now, no need any hack. Thank you